# Circular Area maximising with polygons included. Help?

Tags: geometry, optimization, vectors, euclidean-geometry, circles

given n concentric circles, each of which contain a point that can move on that circle, with radius’s {r1, r2, …., rn}, find the geometric(angular) arrangement of these points to get the polygon with maximum area.

the setup looks like the following:
[image]

[image]

the approach I used was to assign to each point a position vector to get a convenient means to calculate areas using cross-product. It ran into problems because of the following:
1) which vectors should be positioned together
2)the problem seems to be dependent on both, the number of point and their respective radiuses.

If there was some general method maybe using some inequality that assigns positions to the vectors or some other method that somehow automatically takes care of the nitty-gritty that would be great.

I'm not exactly sure what to field to mark the problem in. All ideas and inputs and solutions are appreciated.

[I have a high-school math background]

Comment: Interesting question.  Where does it come from?  Have you tried solving it for a triangle (three circles)?  Four circles?

Comment: @saulspatz yeah I did try it but it starts to get complex pretty quick. Initial reaction was to go with a spiral like arrangement based on visual areas. But even with 3 points, changing their radius can possibly change arrangements .problem I devised last year while in math class.

Comment: Havent been able to get close to solving even the 4 circles case

Comment: By rotational symmetry, you can simplify the problem somewhat by fixing the outer most point anywhere.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed You can also assume that the smallest radius is $1$.

Comment: Do you know about partial derivatives?  Or about derivatives at all?

Comment: Put in a polar coordinate and let the center be the origin. Suppose $P_i$ is on the circle of radius $r_i$, then the directed area of the polygon $P_1\cdots P_r$ is $\frac12\sum_{i=1}^r r_ir_{i+1}\sin \theta_i$, where $\theta_i$ is the difference of the angular coordinate of $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$. Then you can maximize this function by Lagrange multiplier under the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^r\theta_i = 2\pi$.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed I initially did that to get a base for an angular arrangement

Comment: @saulspatz yeah good point, thanks

Comment: @saulspatz yes I'm okay with derivatives and somewhat familiar with handling partial derivatives

Comment: @HwChu this is basically summing half the cross product right? Will the "lagrange mutiplier" allow us to maximize the term so obtained? There is the problem of both the radiuses and angles being rather unconnected

Comment: For $n = 4$, the optimal solution is placing the 4 points on +ve $x$-axis, +ve $y$-axis, -ve $x$-axis and -ve $y$-axis (in that order).

Comment: @achillehui What does ve mean?

Comment: @achillehui can you prove that?

Comment: +ve is a short hand for positive. not sure where I learn that.

Comment: @John_Nash For $n = 4$, area = $\frac12\left|\sum_{i} r_i r_{i+1}\sin\theta_i\right| \le \frac12 \sum_i r_i r_{i+1}$ and the arrangement I mentioned before achieve this upper bound.

Comment: @HwChu could you give an example with n=5

Comment: Although I'm not an expert and I can't prove my solution, here it goes: Maximum area is circular shape. To aproximate to it, assign polar $\alpha=2\pi/n*i$ to each point `i`. I guess this spiral is what results after Lagrange's method.

Comment: Lagrange multiplier is a way to numerically find the extremal value of the target function. For this you need to be able to compute partial derivatives (so I guess this is what saulspatz had in his mind). For this question, you will see that local maxima/minima occurs when $r_ir_{i+1}\cos \theta_i$ are the same for each $i$. In general you can only expect a numeric solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an analysis using HwChu's suggestion of Lagrange multipliers.  As usual, [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx) have a very accessible discussion of this subject.  Since the constraint is $\sum\theta_i=2\pi$, we have, in the notation of the notes, $$\begin{align}
f(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_n)&=\frac12\sum r_ir_{i+1}\sin\theta_i,\\
g(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_n)&=\sum\theta_i
\end{align}$$
(In the first equation, when $i=n$ we interpret $i+1$ as meaning $1$.)

We have $$\begin{align}
{\partial f\over\partial\theta_i}&=\frac12r_ir_{i+1}\cos\theta_i\\
\lambda{\partial g\over\partial\theta_i}&=\lambda
\end{align}
$$
So we see that $$\theta_i=\arccos\left(C\over r_ir_{i+1}\right)$$ for some constant $C$ such that $$\sum\theta_i = 2\pi$$

Except in the $n=4$ case, where we can take $C=0$, I think this will have to be solved numerically.

For example, for $n=5$ and radii $1,3,5,7,9$ [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20acos%28x%2F3%29%2Bacos%28x%2F9%29%2Bacos%28x%2F15%29%2Bacos%28x%2F35%29%2Bacos%28x%2F63%29%3D2pi%20) gives $C=2.53046$

**EDIT**

There's appears to be an oversight here.  Suppose we have the six radii $$1,3,5,7,9,15$$ so that the products of successive radii are $$ 3,15,35,63,135,15$$  The largest possible value of $C$ in the above is $3$, for otherwise $\arccos\left({C\over3}\right)$ is undefined.  Now$$ \cos^{-1}\left({3\over3}\right)+
\cos^{-1}\left({3\over15}\right)+
\cos^{-1}\left({3\over35}\right)+
\cos^{-1}\left({3\over63}\right)+
\cos^{-1}\left({3\over135}\right)+
\cos^{-1}\left({3\over15}\right)=7.295585>2\pi$$
Since $\cos^{-1}$ is a decreasing function, we see that the condition cannot be satisfied, which means that the maximum doesn't occur when the origin is inside the polygon.  This raises two questions.  First, when we do find a critical point by the above method, is it possible that it doesn't correspond to a global maximum, and second, how do we deal with the case where we know the maximum-area polygon doesn't contain the center?

Comment: When we put c back into the formula, in what order have we numbered ri and ri+1 (basically to get the theta i) . Would be quite helpful if you could as an example give the theta values corresponding to the respective radiuses using the calculated C

Comment: With $C=2.530463592649571$, I get the following angles (in degrees):$$32.48971682500606\\
80.28789817427759\\
85.85395738640754\\
87.69803338454467\\
73.67039416151239$$